# Add a line space in an HTML view before a specific text

Tags: javascript, html, angular, key-value

Have a array of objects and to iterate through each object to display it on HTML.Need to add an line breaker if a specific key is repeated.

```
var arr = [{color: red},{fruit: grapes},{city: Bangalore} {ice-cream: chocolate},{color: yellow},{fruit: orange},{color: pink}]
```

Tried code

```
<div class="bx--row" *ngFor="let obj of arr; let i = index;">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of obj | keyvalue">  
             <span class="bx--col-xs-5 bx--col-md-5"> {{item.key}} :</span>
             <span class="bx--col-xs-5 bx--col-md-5">{{item.value}} </span>
             </ng-container>
           </div>
```

Expected output :

```
color: red
fruit:grapes
city: Bangalore
ice-cream: chocolate
//line breaker/space here before having key "color" repeating
color: yellow
fruit: orange

color: pink
```

unexpected output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you're after, but you could check if the property is `color` using `*ngIf` directive.

```html
<div class="bx--row" *ngFor="let obj of arr; let i = index; let first = first">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of obj | keyvalue">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.key === 'color' && !first">
      <br />
    </ng-container>
    <span class="bx--col-xs-5 bx--col-md-5"> {{item.key}} :</span>
    <span class="bx--col-xs-5 bx--col-md-5">{{item.value}} </span>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vf3biv)

#### Update

```html
<div class="bx--row" *ngFor="let obj of arr; let i = index; let first = first">
  <ng-container *ngIf="obj.color && !first">
    <br />
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of obj | keyvalue">
    <span class="bx--col-xs-5 bx--col-md-5"> {{item.key}} :</span>
    <span class="bx--col-xs-5 bx--col-md-5">{{item.value}} </span>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: @Micheal D Thanks,i tried like this but the line break happens after key color....i want it before that

Comment: Are you sure? We check before printing the values. It works here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vf3biv. I've also edited the answer to avoid rendering a linebreak if it's the first element of the array.

Comment: @Micheal D...Have added a image on my question

Comment: I am not exactly sure without replicating the issue. Please make a Stackblitz if possible. Nevertheless, I've updated the answer with the condition moved outside the inner loop. See if it solves the issue.